# Finding a contradiction to prove $ \sup (A + B) \ge \sup A + \sup B $

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

$ A + B $ is defined as $ \{a + b|a \in A, b \in B\} $. To prove the statement in the title, I want to try contradicting $ \sup (A + B) < \sup A + \sup B $.

Here is my thought process: Suppose not $ s = \sup (A + B) $ and $ s < \sup A + \sup B $, then here are the implications of these two assumptions:

\begin{gather}
s = \sup (A + B) \implies \forall c \in A + B: c \le s \quad \text{(1)}
\end{gather}

\begin{align}
s < \sup A + \sup B &\implies ((\forall a \in A, b \in B: a \le u_a \land b \le u_b) \implies s < u_a + u_b) \\
&\implies (s \ge u_a + u_b \implies (\exists a \in A, b \in B: a > u_a \lor b > u_b)) \\
&\implies (s \ge w \implies (\forall x \exists a \in A, b \in B: a > w - x \lor b > x)) && \text{(2)} \\
&(w = u_a + u_b, x = u_b)
\end{align}

From (1) and (2) we have:

\begin{gather}
\forall c \in A + B: \forall x \exists a \in A, b \in B: a > c - x \lor b > x
\end{gather}

It feels like there should be a contradiction here by finding a counterexample for x, but I couldn't find one. What am I doing wrong? Are my assumptions not enough to prove a contradiction?

Comment: There's a much simpler way. Pick any $a \in A$ and $b \in B,$ and note that $a+b \leq \sup (A + B).$ Now take supremum over $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ to get $\sup A + \sup B \leq \sup (A+B).$

Comment: I agree with @Edd that his way is simpler. However it is a good idea to practice contradiction. It might be useful to use the "epsilon definition of supremum" in order to get the contradiction you want

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the epsilon definition. That would make life easier.